# How to get compiled angular directive html outside of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following situation. I created angularjs directive, which works great inside angularjs world. But I need to get compiled version of that directive from code which lives outside of angular. I know it's ugly way of doing this, from angularjs prospective, but right now I have js library, which accepts only html, and makes some transformations on that, and returns html, which I need. That js library knows nothing about Angular, and works only with html. For demo purposes I've created simple directive, simple controller, and simple page. You can see it on plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ea4oNINTG3qc5Zj1OePj) . Directive should be compiled and for example alerted after button click.

Here is js code:

```
function drawDirective()
{
    var htmlForCompile = '<div ng-controller="testController as tc"><coold settings="tc.settings"></coold></div>';
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'examples']);

    var htmlOut = '';
    injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
    //how to receive scope ???
    var scope = angular.element(htmlForCompile).scope();
    htmlOut = $compile(htmlForCompile)(scope);
    alert(htmlOut);
    });
}


angular.module('examples', []);

(function () 
 {
    var cnt = 'testController';
    angular.module('examples').controller(cnt, testController);//register
    testController.$inject = ['$scope'];

   function testController($scope) {
          var vm = this;
          var settings = {};
          settings.value = "this is test output";
          vm.settings = settings;
    }

    angular.module('examples').directive('coold', function ($compile) {
        return coold($compile);
    });

    function coold(compile){
    var directiveReturn = {
        cmp : compile,
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
            return 'template.html';
        },
        scope: {
            settings: "=settings"
        }
    };
    return directiveReturn;
}
})();
```

Html code:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="examples" id="insideAngular">
      <div ng-controller="testController as tc">
        <coold settings="tc.settings"></coold>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="nonAngularJS">
      <button id="click" onclick="return drawDirective()">Draw directive</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

and template which is used by directive:

```
<div>
  <span>{{settings.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you load that library before angular and then do the html operations inside of a directive and then output the altered html in whichever fashion you need? You might have to use a $timeout function in the directive to allow angular to compile first so that you can utilize your non angular external library.

Comment: Here is a link to an answer that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617502/angular-ngrepeat-update-after-html-changed/35617690#35617690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I did not quite understand your demand.

I'm change your directive `coold` and function `drawDirective`.

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3meaULVAwjhbXdn7y5Cb?p=preview).

```
function drawDirective()
{
  var htmlForCompile = document.querySelector("#id_1");
  console.log(htmlForCompile);
}


angular.module('examples', []);

(function () 
{
 var cnt = 'testController';
angular.module('examples').controller(cnt, testController);//register
testController.$inject = ['$scope'];

 function testController($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      var settings = {};
      settings.value = "this is test output";
      settings.id ="id_1";
      vm.settings = settings;
}

angular.module('examples').directive('coold', function ($compile) {
    return coold($compile);
});

function coold(compile){
var directiveReturn = {
    cmp : compile,
    restrict: 'AEC',
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
        return 'template.html';
    },
    scope: {
        settings: "=settings"
    }
};
return directiveReturn;
}
})();
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="examples" id="insideAngular">
  <div ng-controller="testController as tc">
    <coold settings="tc.settings"></coold>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="nonAngularJS">
  <button id="click" onclick="return drawDirective()">Draw directive</button>
</div>

 </body>

</html>
```

**And template**

```
<div id="{{settings.id}}>
  <span>{{settings.value}}</span>
</div>
```

### UPDATED

Of course, if you want to change the html template in the function `drawDirective`, the angular, these changes will not see.

To angulyar saw changes you need to write a function `drawDirective` as follows.

```
function drawDirective()
{
 var htmlForCompile = document.querySelector("#id_1");
 var scope = angular.element(htmlForCompile).scope();
 scope.settings.value+=" drawing";
 scope.$apply();
}
```

More about [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).